# Shouldn't any relabelling of vertices in a graph preserve isomorphism?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Say $G$ and $H$ are two isomorphic graphs. There is the following theorem:

Two simple graphs $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic if and only if there exists a permutation matrix $P$ such that $A_G=PA_HP^t$.

**But shouldn't this be a ''for all'' permutation matrices $P$ we have  $A_G=PA_HP^t$?**

It seems to me that every permutation matrix corresponds to a relabelling of the vertices of a graph. And it seems to me that any such relabelling will preserve all properties of the graph. Therefore, if $G$ and $H$ are isomorpphic then they still are isomorphic after any possible relabelling (permutation) of the vertices.

Why is this not so?

Comment: Where did your version of the theorem come from?

Comment: @MatthewTowers For $G=H$ we have $AP = PA$. What is wrong with that? The permutation matrix $P$ consists of a permutation of the identity matrix. It seems to me that there is no reason why it shouldn't commute with $A$. What am I missing? But even if this was going to turn out contradictory in some sense: I still think that I can relabel any graph in any way and still have the same graph. Because relabelling doesn't change vertex degrees and cycles.

Comment: @JMP My head.. .

Answer (score 1):

The adjacency matrix $A_G$ isn't solely a graph-theoretical property of $G$. The matrix $A_G$ is determined once we have picked

1. The graph $G$;
2. An ordering of the vertices of $G$.

If we order the vertices differently, we get different adjacency matrices. This is where permutation matrices come in: if $P$ is a permutation matrix, then $P A_G P^{\mathsf T}$ gives us another adjacency matrix that comes from a different ordering.

Thus, even if $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic, we should not expect $A_G = A_H$, because to obtain $A_G$ and $A_H$, we picked an ordering of the vertices of $G$ and an ordering of the vertices of $H$. If $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic, **and** we chose compatible orderings of their vertices, **then** we should expect $A_G = A_H$.

If we did not choose compatible orderings, then the best we can say about isomorphic graphs $G,H$ is this: "Some adjacency matrix of $H$ is equal to $A_G$". The possible adjacency matrices of $H$ are given by $P A_H P^{\mathsf T}$ for various choices of $P$. Thus, we get the statement you quoted: $A_G = P A_H P^{\mathsf T}$ for some $H$.